# drupal rss feed not displaying in IE7

Tags: drupal, rss, internet-explorer-7, feed

I'm generating some RSS feeds from my Drupal site. They work fine in Firefox and IE8, but in IE6 and 7 it is displaying the XML. The feed location is at http://www.leanarts.org.uk/general/feed.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

IE6 does not have a native RSS reader, so plain XML is perfectly normal and expected. If a "prettified" view in IE6 is important, you might want to look at using client side XSLT to smarten it up (see this answer [How to display Atom/RSS feeds in browser with custom XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045770/how-to-display-atom-rss-feeds-in-browser-with-custom-xslt) for some useful pointers for example).

Not sure about IE7 I'm afraid, I don't have a copy to hand right now. Your feed seems to be meeting all the publishing requirements for IE7 though [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rssteam/windows-rss-publishers-guide-work-in-progress)

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for your answer, and taking the time to have a look. I may just live with IE7 not working and just give users a warning message for it. (I was using IE Tester to test IE7).