# Associating XSLT with Atom feed so it renders in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, xslt, stylesheet, atom-feed, xsl-stylesheet

I'm generating an ATOM feed with this header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/atom2html.xsl"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

I think this used to work in Chrome - visiting the URL showed an HTML rendering of the Atom feed. However, some time in the last few months (I think), Chrome's handling of Atom feeds changed so that you can't see the content without installing a plugin like "Feed intent viewer".

Is it still possible to transform an Atom feed using XSLT like this, so it will render on Chrome? What do I need to do? (Or are my assumptions about what used to work wrong?)

Comment: This might not be your issue, but do note, Chrome will not run transforms which reside on local storage.

Comment: Yeah, in this case it's not - but good to note.

Comment: Could you supply a sample input XML document, your atom2html.xsl style-sheet, and the version of Chrome you are using.

Comment: I think your question is asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045770

Comment: So it boils down to the MIME type of your feed document. Change it to application/xml, and you should be good.

Comment: Also see verdy_p's answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981524

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display Atom/RSS feeds in browser with custom XSLT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045770/how-to-display-atom-rss-feeds-in-browser-with-custom-xslt)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the content-type is currently "text/html; charset=UTF-8" so I'll try application/xml.